# Is "で一発だ an expression?

Tags: expressions, idioms

> こりゃたまげた!　あっという間に見つけちまうんだね

I'm shocked. You found the food in an instant

And his reply

> ああ?　食い物なんて匂いで一発だ

From context I can gather it seems to be akin to ... I found it asap because of the smell but I'm not sure how the sentence is being constructed

"When it comes to food, with the smell..."

Comment: Do you understand [一発](https://jisho.org/word/%E4%B8%80%E7%99%BA)?

Answer (score 2):

The sentence structure is rather simple though it does not admit simple translation into English because 一発 wouldn't correspond to a simple English word.

The sentence is

- 食い物は匂いで一発だ

with なんて adding 'such things as foods'. So literally:

- Foods are 一発 by the smell.

[一発](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E4%B8%80%E7%99%BA/#je-3963) means literally 'one shot' or 'one trial'. (一瞬 has the similar usage: この宿題は一瞬だ would mean '(doing) this homework is one instant')

Here you can think *(detecting) food is a matter of single trial by the smell* (if preserving the structure as much as possible).